# How to evidence a particular page on Google SERP?

Tags: seo, googlebot

I noticed that some results of searching on Google are not a single url but a single url with a two-column list of what I call 'important links' of this website.

For example: If you open Google and search for "amazon.it", without the double quote, you got this:

[image: Results of google search for amazon.it]

As you can see, some links are evidenced directly on SERP ("eBook Kindle", for example).

I know I can produce a sitemap.xml for Google bot pleasure, but, my question is: **How can I evidence some particular link of my website to be presented in this way in Google's SERP?**.

As far I know, there is no a special syntax in the sitemap protocol to 'force' or 'suggest' this to search engines. For future readers: [this is the link to the sitemap protocol](http://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are called [sitelinks](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/47334?hl=en) and they are unrelated to sitemaps. Google only shows them when:

1. It understands the structure of your website (typically via the structures in URLs).
2. It trusts your website's content (no spam).
3. The content/link is relevant and useful for the corresponding user query.

Some say implementing breadcrumbs helps Google find SiteLinks candidates, but this has never been confirmed and may be completely false.

Comment: Center ! Thanks for the link, I discovered an entire collection of other usefull Google tools !